# ReSharper gives 'possible NullReference' Warning on Functor

Tags: c#, resharper, nullreferenceexception, func

I have written a function with a functor and resharper is giving me a "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'" Warning.

This is my function:

```
public bool MyWhere(Func<FooClass, BarStruct> functor)
{
     _ = functor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(functor));
     // ... do some unrelated magic.
     return true;
}
```

Now when I try to use the function like

```cs
someService.MyWhere(x => x.MemberFunction);
```

ReSharper displays the warning for me. And I've already tried using the `[JetBrains.Annotation.NotNull]` Attribute in the function signature.

If anyone knows how to supress this warning, or knows where I should put a null check, much appreciated!

Comment: I copied the code provided and am not getting the warning. Latest Resharper.

Comment: @mxmissile Do you have your Value-Analysis setting set to "Pessimistic"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ReSharper, but I suspect the warning occurs because the lambda argument, `x`, could be null, not because `functor` could be null.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, I just need to know how to specify that the ``x`` can never be null.